# can't open doc files when long path in macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, catalina, ms-office

I have MacBook Air 2013, macOS Catalina 10.15.5, MS Office 2019 (ver. 16.37). When I try to open doc or docx files from Finder, and they have long path, it just won't open. Word starts (icon jumps in dock, but nothing happens).
e.g. /users/me/downloads/file.docx — if I double click on this file in Finder, Word will open it, but if I have long path, e.g. /user/me/downloads/files from rick sanchez about portal gun/general questions how to use portal gun/..../file.docx — if I double click on this file in Finder, Word will start but file won't open.  Is it only me and how to fix it? How to understand is it because of Office and it is needed to reinstall it or it is macOS bug?

Comment: Did the 5 dots in the pathname maintain its original name?  It might be a Word error. I tried a long pathname using pages and it worked fine.  Maybe you can change the extension on the file to pages and see if Pages will open file.

Comment: Not certain, but I believe it is Office.  Max path lengths around 250.

Comment: @jmh Pages works fine, it's only with Word and Excel files, so I guess it's Office bug. (